# Proper Divisor mash-up

Tags: code-golf, math, number, number-theory, division

A [*proper divisor*](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProperDivisor.html) is a [divisor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor) of a number *n*, which is not *n* itself. For example, the proper divisors of 12 are 1, 2, 3, 4 and 6.

You will be given **an integer** *x*, *x* ≥ 2, *x ≤ 1000*. Your task is to sum all the ***highest* proper divisors** of the integers from *2* to *x* (inclusive) (OEIS [A280050](http://oeis.org/A280050)).

#### Example (with `x = 6`):

- Find all the integers between 2 and 6 (inclusive): 2,3,4,5,6.
- Get the proper divisors of all of them, and pick the highest ones from each number:

  - 2 -> **1**
  - 3 -> **1**
  - 4 -> 1, **2**
  - 5 -> **1**
  - 6 -> 1, 2, **3**.
- Sum the highest proper divisors: `1 + 1 + 2 + 1 + 3 = 8`.
- The final result is 8.

## Test Cases

```
Input  |  Output
-------+---------
       |
 2     | 1
 4     | 4
 6     | 8
 8     | 13
 15    | 41
 37    | 229
 100   | 1690
 1000  | 165279
```

## Rules

- [Default Loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) apply.
- You can take input and provide output by [any standard method](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods).
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), the shortest valid submission in each language wins! Have Fun!

Comment: [Sandbox.](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges/13085#13085)

Comment: If you're going to sandbox something, leave it in there for more than two hours.

Comment: @PeterTaylor I sandboxed the post only to receive feedback, because this is a very simple challenge which I would usually not post in the sandbox at all. BTW thanks for the edit.

Answer (score 13):

## [Oasis](https://github.com/Adriandmen/Oasis), 4 bytes

#### Code:

```
nj+U
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08sziz@/z8vSzv0////FgA)

#### Explanation:

Extended version:

```
nj+00

    0   = a(0)
   0    = a(1)

a(n) =

n       # Push n
 j      # Get the largest divisor under n
  +     # Add to a(n - 1)
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 10 bytes

```
⟦bb{fkt}ᵐ+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r//9H8ZUlJ1WnZJbUPt07Q/v/f0MDA4H8UAA)

Comment: You have clearly won this in all languages so far :))

Comment: [-2](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r//9H8ZdVp2SW1pxdp//9vaGBg8D8KAA)

Answer (score 5):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), <s>13</s> <s>9</s> 8 bytes

1 byte thanks to jacoblaw.

```
tsm*FtPh
```

[Test suite](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=tsm%2aFtPh&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=2%0A4%0A6%0A8%0A15%0A37%0A100%0A1000&debug=0).

### How it works

The largest proper divisor is the product of the prime factors except the smallest one.

Comment: [8 bytes](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=tsm%2aFtPh&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=2%0A4%0A6%0A8%0A15%0A37%0A100%0A1000&debug=0)

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 50 bytes

```python
f=lambda n,k=2:n/k and(f(n,k+1),n/k+f(n-1))[n%k<1]
```

This is *slow* and can't even cope with input **15** on TIO.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DYxBCoMwFETX9RSzCSYY2yZIKVJ7kdKFrUqD@iNJXHj69A/M4j2Y2Y7082SzWzcfEuIRC@45jimM3z1E52lxq0vSXDkqT93Sr5@hB@m5sy1dZvQ0yEkyV0ZpFhVDbZR6kZgf5p0nH0BwBKvRaNw07m1x2oKjJEthdtRPCLuXEOAX8Foplf8)

However, memoization (*thanks @musicman523*) can be used to verify all test cases.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VU5Ra8IwGHw2v@Jeis2MrK3ODamDMRiUbT5svgwRcTbBUJuUNH1wY7@9pikie8mXu/vu7qtO9qBV0gqjSxhe68bsOWRZaWNxQzxdn@orQ2puzVGW0oYfb9l7ttp@rp6eXxk83GbLl2yZrb4Y/kFKvY/vG1NLrXp/jDTFJKKtWBx35Xe@g2LFIpmr2wI7lYcidHgUU@aIkQPjmNK1Coo03rQ5Fyh5qeUPDwWdk0EHsMDvHxl02oEfK25cAArHJt3GQAp4gkJpC6l8QCd487rXNm5d9F@nGG4b0y9edHIh@wpChHNcT3FYG6guPmGYMswYHhjiO4bJvZtR5J/I9VZGKhsOg2mD8SOCWTNE4C90/ZTS9gw)

#### Alternate version, 52 bytes

At the cost of 2 bytes, we can choose whether to compute `f(n,k+1)` or `n/k+f(n-1)`.

```python
f=lambda n,k=2:n>1and(n%k and f(n,k+1)or n/k+f(n-1))
```

With some trickery, this works for all test cases, even on TIO.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VYxNi8IwGITP9lfMpdhoxMb6haggCwth1YP24kmqthhq35QkPfjr3dg9LF5meB6YqZ/uril5FUZXMLnVjbnmUFWtjUMvaLV92n8T2NyZh6qUiw5buZPp@Zhuvn44WjzL/bfcy/TE8YGMtbv82hirNP3tBZZLJDF7FatHVl1uGYiXq9GC1iKjW0RhCd8oIq/7gmkDGpZ9jwPB/OjNUIQRx5hjyjHnEBOOZOY7jtuIF0GnNopc1A3HDQZrhNOmixD@833M/NEv)

Comment: Since `f` is a [pure function](https://www.sitepoint.com/functional-programming-pure-functions/), you can memoize it to run the larger cases on [TIO](https://tio.run/##TU/LbsMgEDx3v2IvVliFtMVqq8qK@yNRDm4NCrJZLIwPSdVvd4E@kpGQmGGY2Z3O8eS5Xq2bfIg4n2dI537WMeiPJczW82idjUI9JhBArw067by9aGGoAUzIHFv8/CosO056nHQQLIe2/jVlWINZI2Qf0XL5eH39izoUzzElmnL7NwQdl8C3HriRfzphNe3Yufe@w9Le8MOAHfeiZG0VySRsE9kpogNXw14dV5O6rksBGB@Q84C1xCeJLxJfJarnBu6mYDmKTaUW3L1hVS8brPJOeVQiWr8B "Python 2 – Try It Online")

Comment: Right, not being able to use a decorator threw me off. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

### [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 7 bytes

```
ṁȯΠtptḣ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//@HOxhPrzy0oKSh5uGPx////jc0B)

### Explanation

Husk has no built-in for computing the divisors directly (yet), so I'm using prime factorization instead.
The largest proper divisor of a number is the product of its prime factors except the smallest one.
I map this function over the range from 2 to the input, and sum the results.

```
ṁȯΠtptḣ  Define a function:
      ḣ  Range from 1 to input.
     t   Remove the first element (range from 2).
ṁ        Map over the list and take sum:
 ȯ        The composition of
    p     prime factorization,
   t      tail (remove smallest prime) and
  Π       product.
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 6 bytes

```
ÆḌ€Ṫ€S
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9w28MdPY@a1jzcuQpIBv///9/QwMAAAA)

### How it works

```
ÆḌ€Ṫ€S
ÆḌ€    map proper divisor (1 would become empty array)
           implicitly turns argument into 1-indexed range
   Ṫ€  map last element
     S sum
```

Answer (score 4):

### Haskell, <s>48</s> <s>46</s> 43 bytes

```
f 2=1
f n=until((<1).mod n)pred(n-1)+f(n-1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P03ByNaQK00hz7Y0ryQzR0PDxlBTLzc/RSFPs6AoNUUjT9dQUzsNTP3PTczMU7BVKCjKzCtRUFHITSxQSFOINtIx0THTsdAxNNUxNtcxNDAAYYPY/wA)

Edit: @rogaos saved two bytes. Thanks!

Edit II: ... and @xnor another 3 bytes.

Comment: -2 bytes: `f 2=1
f n=last[d|d<-[1..n-1],mod n d<1]+f(n-1)`

Comment: @rogaos: Thanks! I've tried the explicit recursion myself, but didn't remove `sum`, so I thought it isn't shorter.

Comment: `until` saves some more: `until((<1).mod n)pred(n-1)+f(n-1)`

Answer (score 4):

### JavaScript (ES6), 40 bytes

```js
f=(n,i=2)=>n<2?0:n%i?f(n,i+1):n/i+f(n-1)
```

```html
<input type=number oninput=o.textContent=f(this.value)><pre id=o>
```

A number equals the product of its highest proper divisor and its smallest prime factor.

Comment: stack overflows for `n>352`(at least in this snippet, dont know if it is my browser/machine dependency) while you are supposed to support at least upto `n=1000`.

Comment: @officialaimm It works for `n=1000` if you use e.g. `node --stack_size=8000`.

Answer (score 4):

## MATL, 12 bytes

```
q:Q"@Z\l_)vs
```

Try it at [MATL Online](https://matl.io/?code=q%3AQ%22%40Z%5Cl_%29vs&inputs=37&version=20.1.1)

**Explanation**

```
        % Implicitly grab input (N)
q       % Subtract one
:       % Create an array [1...(N-1)]
Q       % Add one to create [2...N]
"       % For each element
  @Z\   % Compute the divisors of this element (including itself)
  l_)   % Grab the next to last element (the largest that isn't itself)
  v     % Vertically concatenate the entire stack so far
  s     % Sum the result
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>8+2=10</s> <s>8</s> 6 bytes

```
òâ1 xo
```

[Test it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=8uIxIHhv&input=MTAw)

- 1 byte saved thanks to ETHproductions.

---

### Explanation

```
    :Implicit input of integer U.
ò   :Generate an array of integers from 1 to U, inclusive
â   :Get the divisors of each number,
1   :  excluding itself.
x   :Sum the main array
o   :by popping the last element from each sub-array.
    :Implicit output of result
```

Comment: Note that `-x` counts as two bytes according to [this post](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/13058/42545). However, I think you can save a byte with `ò2_â1 o` (`â` excludes the original number when given an argument)

Comment: Thanks, @ETHproductions; I'd missed both those things. I wonder does that apply retroactively to all solutions where we counted flags as 1 byte? I was working up an alternative solution that didn't use a flag anyway; pointing out `â`'s argument got me the saving I was looking for.

Comment: I would assume so, since we weren't really following a consensus before. BTW, I had been playing with `õ Å` before and found a couple 8- and 9-byters: `õ Åx_/k g`, `õ Åx_k Å×`, `õ Åx_â¬o`. And by combining `õ` and `Å` with your genius `xo` trick I found a 7-byte solution :-)

Comment: @ETHproductions note that this is not the consensus anymore. Flags do not count towards the byte count.

Answer (score 4):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), <s>31</s> 24 bytes

7 bytes thanks to Martin Ender.

```
.+
$*
M!&`(1+)(?=\1+$)
1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P9fT5tLRYvLV1EtQcNQW1PD3jbGUFtFk8vw/39DAwMDAA)

### How it works

The regex `/^(1+)\1+$/` captures the largest proper divisor of a certain number represented in unary. In the code, the `\1+` is turned to a lookahead syntax.

Answer (score 4):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>9</s> 8 bytes

-1 Byte thanks to [Leaky Nun](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/48934/leaky-nun)'s prime factor trick in his Pyth answer

```
L¦vyÒ¦PO
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f/f59CyssrDkw4tC/D//9/QwMAAAA)

#### Explanation

```
L¦vyÒ¦PO
L¦       # Range [2 .. input]
  vy     # For each...
    Ò¦    # All prime factors except the first one
      P   # Product
       O  # Sum with previous results
         # Implicit print
```

Alternative 8 Byte solution (That doesnt work on TIO)

```
L¦vyÑ¨θO
```

and ofc alternative 9 Byte solution (That works on TIO)

```
L¦vyÑ¨®èO
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 2 (PyPy)](http://pypy.org/), <s>73</s> <s>71</s> 70 bytes

```python
n=input();r=[0]*n;d=1
while n:n-=1;r[d+d::d]=n/d*[d];d+=1
print sum(r)
```

Not the shortest Python answer, but this just breezes through the test cases. TIO handles inputs up to **30,000,000** without breaking a sweat; my desktop computer handles **300,000,000** in a minute.

At the cost of **2 bytes**, the condition `n>d` could be used for a ~10% speed-up.

*Thanks to @xnor for the `r=[0]*n` idea, which saved 3 bytes!*

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcpBCoAgEADAe6/wqEWkdVP2JeJtA4XaFlPC11vQnIdbiRetMzduvRMk4lqkchm8DiM5BDM8MR27IEszGJc9TmgtBqAFR4/B4fQdzomKuOsps@p9078X)

Comment: Funny, I just wrote [basically the same code](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P882M6@gtERDkyvHNtowViuPK9vW0Dq1IjVZKSfaSCvbyio71jY6O1ZLI08/W9dQ0zpbGyivBFRXUJSZV6JQXJqrkaOpCzTJ0MDAAAA).

Comment: `l=[0]*n` should allow you to get rid of `-2`. `exec` kinda kills the speed, but even a `while` loop would be shorter than my approach.

Comment: [This](https://tio.run/##JcpNCoAgEEDhfadw6Q@S1U7xJOJugoSaBlPC05vQW348auW4cdXUqPWOPiHVwoXLPpgo0YFfpvdI585wBpsDKLAWog8QJR@kF@FAjYlywsKeevEset/M3wc "Python 2 (PyPy) – Try It Online") seems to be marginally faster than my approach. Mind if I edit that into my answer?

Comment: Please, go for it.

Comment: @Dennis This would have totally won a [tag:fastest-code] challege

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder Not in PyPy, but yes, sieves do fine for this kind of problem.

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder [Challenge accepted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/128232/39242)!

Answer (score 4):

## Mathematica, 30 bytes

```
Divisors[i][[-2]]~Sum~{i,2,#}&
```

Answer (score 3):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 56 bytes

```php
for($i=1;$v||$argn>=$v=++$i;)$i%--$v?:$v=!$s+=$v;echo$s;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jX5BRwJVaVJRfFF@UWpBfVJKZl65R5xrv5x/i6eyqac2lkliUnmerZGhgYKBk/T8tv0hDJdPW0FqlrKYGLGVnq1Jmq62tkmmtqZKpqqurUmZvBRRRVCnWBspYpyZn5KsUW///DwA)

Answer (score 3):

## [Prolog (SWI)](http://www.swi-prolog.org), 72 bytes

```
f(A,B):-A=2,B=1;C is A-1,f(C,D),between(2,A,E),divmod(A,E,S,0),B is D+S.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcyxDkAwGEXhVzH2j1tpjcTQap/AYhatNEFFhccv9vOd44xrXHh6Qs6eKWhquOpq6E62fRFSobiEZz0MYXLX49zOaihYwhzuLc6fsRggCPrPTTlU/0kKITBS9QI)

Answer (score 3):

## [C# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), <strike>74</strike> 72 bytes

```cs
n=>{int r=0,j;for(;n>1;n--)for(j=n;--j>0;)if(n%j<1){r+=j;j=0;}return r;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lY8/a8MwEMV3f4pbChKNEtn5jyIvhU4tFDp0NopcJJITSEqhGH921w52vXRQ33Do7vTjvVOBKed1B73UpQoB3rz79NU1GybNvQ4KsYpGwZczZ3itDBL6u5o/DXr/DlFfl883VCeDcQF9KaEGmXUoy6bvwEu@sKJ2nggsc4GM0aGxEgVjtuSCmprggz3ltPGP0goruWi9jjeP4EXbiewvyyeHwV308sObqF8MalKTglIBqxXkqcBmBDapwG4EDqnAYYq0TiXy7RQq@Yz1fkSK4phsw/kUbXfk/6BmbFvsZ7v2/mq7Hw)

- 2 bytes shaved thanks to Kevin Cruijssen.

Comment: I know it's been about a year, but you can golf `break` to `j=0`.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen a very simple but effective trick. Nice idea!

Answer (score 3):

## [Cubix](https://github.com/ETHproductions/cubix), 27 <s>39</s> bytes

```
?%\(W!:.U0IU(;u;p+qu.@Op\;;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy5Nyqz4/99eNUYjXNFKL9TAM1TDutS6QLuwVM/BvyDG2vr/f0MDAwMA)

Cubified

```
      ? % \
      ( W !
      : . U
0 I U ( ; u ; p + q u .
@ O p \ ; ; . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . . . . .
      . . .
      . . .
      . . .
```

[Watch It Run](https://ethproductions.github.io/cubix/?code=ICAgICAgPyAlIFwKICAgICAgKCBXICEKICAgICAgOiAuIFUKMCBJIFUgKCA7IHUgOyBwICsgcSB1IC4KQCBPIHAgXCA7IDsgLiAuIC4gLiAuIC4KLiAuIC4gLiAuIC4gLiAuIC4gLiAuIC4KICAgICAgLiAuIC4KICAgICAgLiAuIC4KICAgICAgLiAuIC4K&input=OAo=&speed=20)

- `0IU` Set up the stack with an accumulator, and the starting integer.  U-turn into the outer loop
- `:(?` duplicate the current top of stack, decrement and test
- `\pO@` if zero loop around the cube to a mirror, grab the bottom of stack, output and halt
- `%\!` if positive, mod, relect and test.

  - `u;.W` if truthy, u-turn, remove mod result and lane change back into inner loop
  - `U;p+qu;;\(` if falsey, u-turn, remove mod result, bring accumulator to top, add current integer (top) divisor push to bottom and u-turn. Clean up the stack to have just accumulator and current integer, decrement the integer and enter the outer loop again.

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>69</s> <s>63</s> 59 bytes

4 bytes thanks to Dennis.

```python
f=lambda n:n-1and max(j for j in range(1,n)if n%j<1)+f(n-1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Tc5bCoMwEAXQf1cxUAoJfZDEd2kXk1bTRswoMYW6ehulxg7Mz@HeYfrRvTqMJ236zjoYxiHyex5qZ@vH2w66w1Yb7YhgjNFJ3Vpp7pUEvOCJS6zAyA9pQHUWGtAIVuKzJvyIVCvAfXPl9KCIz9KptxodUURQCn52wKOVkpWSQNlKRaAiFONgPF3QN7drcf4zIcot6N@nSzkr2b/OPGsq8nL6Ag)

I set the recursion limit to 2000 for this to work for 1000.

Comment: +1 You have my brownie points! That's the solution I was talking about when saying "shorter than 70 bytes"...

Comment: Also, this works in Python 2 as well

Answer (score 2):

## [Actually](https://github.com/Mego/Seriously), 12 bytes

```
u2x⌠÷R1@E⌡MΣ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0wuKU3Myan8/7/UqOJRz4LD24MMHVwf9Sz0Pbf4/39DAwMDAA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>78 75 73</s> 71 bytes

Not even close to Leaky nun's python answer in byte count.

```python
f=lambda z:sum(max(i for i in range(1,y)if 1>y%i)for y in range(2,z+1))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RclLCoAgEADQq8wmmCEXWrug7mKUNZAfzCC9vNWq5eOFnHbv@lrNeGg7LxrKcF4Wrb6RwfgIDOwgaretqEQmNqCm3DB9l//rRGkVUQ2RXUKDSkr58gE)

Comment: You're getting close to the first revision of my answer... you can check my editing history.

Comment: Oh, haha... I swear I did not steal it... :)

Answer (score 2):

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), <s>36</s> 30 bytes

```
n->sum(i=2,n,i/divisors(i)[2])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYxBCoMwEEWv8nGVwARjWqubeBHpQiiWgXYcEi309DHt5r/3Nl@XxO6pZUUs4qZ8vA3HQELcPvjDeUvZsJ3D3ZZF9fU1AjdBE8tetflFg9WItYQ5EK6EG2EkdD3hMlR6/x9fH04)

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 37 bytes

```
Ａ⁰βＦ…·²Ｎ«Ａ⟦⟧δＦ⮌…¹ι«¿¬﹪ικ⊞δκ»Ａ⁺β⌈δβ»Ｉβ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Nc69CoMwFAXg3afIeC9E0K5O0slBEdfSITFRgzEp@ZFC8dlTWtv1cL7DGRfmRst0SrX3ajZQUMKxyibrCDRm1NGrXQ7MzBIulDTmEUMXNy4dICJ5ZT92u1Mi/m6Qu3RewslKqr5VNRHobIDWiqgtKLp@4j76BQQlK1bHf6wWAjglLXuqLW4gEM9TR9Y7ZQJcmQ/AEauUyqJI@Z5yr98)

Link is to the verbose version. It took me almost all day to figure out how could I solve a non-ASCII-art-related question in Charcoal, but finally I got it and I am very proud of me. :-D

Yes, I am sure this can be golfed a lot. I just translated my C# answer and I am sure things can be done differently in Charcoal. At least it solves the `1000` case in a couple of seconds...

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2 (PyPy)](http://pypy.org/), 145 bytes

Because turning code-golf competitions into fastest-code competitions is fun, here is an O(*n*) algorithm that, on TIO, solves *n* = **5,000,000,000** in 30 seconds.  ([Dennis’s sieve](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/128176/39242) is O(*n* log *n*).)

```python
import sympy
n=input()
def g(i,p,k,s):
 while p*max(p,k)<=n:l=k*p;i+=1;p=sympy.sieve[i];s-=g(i,p,l,n/l*(n/l*k+k-2)/2)
 return s
print~g(1,2,1,-n)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYy9DsIgFEZ3noIRWrCWxMXKkxgHE7G9gd7eAFVZfHX8i99whpOcj0qeFjSaCpVaYaYlZp7KTIWhBaQ1C8ku7spHAYqUV0nuGb9PEBynZj4/xFvKg8V9sL6hAVrbD2S/D5sE7uaOcBqStr8@KOxCIz7wrddGdkYyHl1eI/LEKALm5yh6ZVSvNMpad9v/Xg)

#### How it works

We count the size of the set

*S* = {(*a*, *b*) | 2 ≤ *a* ≤ *n*, 2 ≤ *b* ≤ largest-proper-divisor(*a*)},

by rewriting it as the union, over all primes p ≤ √n, of

*S*<sub>*p*</sub> = {(*p*⋅*d*, *b*) | 2 ≤ *d* ≤ *n*/*p*, 2 ≤ *b* ≤ *d*},

and using the [inclusion–exclusion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle):

|*S*| = ∑ (−1)<sup>*m* − 1</sup> |*S*<sub>*p*<sub>1</sub></sub> ∩ ⋯ ∩ *S*<sub>*p*<sub>*m*</sub></sub>| over *m* ≥ 1 and primes *p*<sub>1</sub> < ⋯ < *p*<sub>*m*</sub> ≤ √n,

where

*S*<sub>*p*<sub>1</sub></sub> ∩ ⋯ ∩ *S*<sub>*p*<sub>*m*</sub></sub> = {(*p*<sub>1</sub>⋯*p*<sub>*m*</sub>⋅*e*, *b*) | 1 ≤ *e* ≤ *n*/(*p*<sub>1</sub>⋯*p*<sub>*m*</sub>), 2 ≤ *b* ≤ *p*<sub>1</sub>⋯*p*<sub>*m* − 1</sub>*e*},
|*S*<sub>*p*<sub>1</sub></sub> ∩ ⋯ ∩ *S*<sub>*p*<sub>*m*</sub></sub>| = ⌊*n*/(*p*<sub>1</sub>⋯*p*<sub>*m*</sub>)⌋⋅(*p*<sub>1</sub>⋯*p*<sub>*m* − 1</sub>⋅(⌊*n*/(*p*<sub>1</sub>⋯*p*<sub>*m*</sub>)⌋ + 1) − 2)/2.

The sum has *C*⋅*n* nonzero terms, where *C* converges to some constant that’s probably 6⋅(1 − ln 2)/π<sup>2</sup> ≈ 0.186544.  The final result is then |*S*| + *n* − 1.

Comment: Oooh, that's fast...

Answer (score 2):

## [NewStack](https://github.com/LyamBoylan/NewStack/), 5 bytes

Luckily, there's actually a built in.

```
Nᵢ;qΣ
```

### The breakdown:

```
Nᵢ       Add the first (user's input) natural numbers to the stack.
  ;      Perform the highest factor operator on whole stack.
   q     Pop bottom of stack.
    Σ    Sum stack.
```

**In actual English:**

Let's run an example for an input of 8.

`Nᵢ`: Make list of natural numbers from 1 though 8: `1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8`

`;`: Compute the greatest factors: `1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 4`

`q`. Remove the first element: `1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 4`

`Σ` And take the sum: `1+1+2+1+3+1+4` = `13`

Comment: `1+1+2+1+3+1+4` = `13` not `8`. Apart from that: great answer so +1.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Whoops, thanks for catching that!

Answer (score 2):

## Java 8, <s>78</s> <s>74</s> 72 bytes

```java
n->{int r=0,j;for(;n>1;n--)for(j=n;j-->1;)if(n%j<1){r+=j;j=0;}return r;}
```

[Port of *@CarlosAlejo*'s C# answer.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/128169/52210)

[Try it here.](https://tio.run/##hY7BasMwEETv@Yq9FCRaGTtN2sBG@YPkkmPpQVXkItVZG1kOBKNvd@Qk1yJYLey8YTROXZRoO0Pu9DfpRvU97JWlcQFgKRhfK23gMJ93ATSbN3FMSkwvTR9UsBoOQCBhIrEbZ4uX5ZvDuvUMaVchCcHnw0lCJ0RSuK0ZvbhtxUf/Kh06WWL0JgyewGOc8JHeDT9NSn9@cmntCc6pIDsGb@n36xsUf7Q7XvtgzkU7hKJLKDTEqNBsye9d/@WrDP/I8E2GV@uM4f0zl1CWecfTEhdxugE)

**Old answer (78 bytes):**

```java
n->{int r=0,i=1,j,k;for(;++i<=n;r+=k)for(j=1,k=1;++j<i;k=i%j<1?j:k);return r;}
```

[Try it here.](https://tio.run/##hY7NasMwEITveYq9FCTsGLs/Sams9gmaS46lB0VRwkrO2shyoAQ/uysnuQbBakHzDTtj1Vkt286Q3btJN6rv4VshXRYASMH4g9IGNvP3KoBm8yYuojLGF6cPKqCGDRBImGj5eZktXpY5yiq3uROH1jORZVhLEj6Tjs@CjdDJKuq2RuEkPtm6@rIfjgtvwuAJvBgnccvohl0TM@5R5xb3cIo12TZ4pOPPLyh@67j964M5Fe0Qii6i0BCjQrNnfm38kL8m@CrB3xO8eksYXtapC2WZdtwt42Kc/gE)

**Explanation (of old answer):**

```java
n->{                    // Method with integer parameter and integer return-type
  int r=0,              //  Result-integers
      i=1,j,k;          //  Some temp integers
  for(;++i<=n;          //  Loop (1) from 2 to `n` (inclusive)
      r+=k)             //    And add `k` to the result after every iteration
    for(j=1,k=1;++j<i;  //   Inner loop (2) from `2` to `i` (exclusive)
      k=i%j<1?j:k       //    If `i` is dividable by `j`, replace `k` with `j`
    );                  //   End of inner loop (2)
                        //  End of loop (2) (implicit / single-line body)
  return r;             //  Return result-integer
}                       // End of method
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2) `-S`, 5 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
ı⁺FṫG
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#aGVhZGVyPSZjb2RlPSVDNCVCMSVFMiU4MSVCQUYlRTElQjklQUJHJmZvb3Rlcj0maW5wdXQ9NiZmbGFncz0tU2U=)

##### Explanation

```python
ı⁺FṫG  # Implicit input
       # Decrement the input
ı      # Map over [1..input-1]:
 ⁺     #  Increment the number
  Fṫ   #  Push the proper divisors
    G  #  Maximum of this list
       # Sum the list
       # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Arturo](https://arturo-lang.io), 32 bytes

```arturo
$=>[∑map..2&=>[x:do factors&]]
```

[Try it!](http://arturo-lang.io/playground?B7ePFw)

Answer (score 1):

## [Lua](https://www.lua.org), 74 bytes

```lua
c=0 for i=2,...do for j=1,i-1 do t=i%j<1 and j or t end c=c+t end print(c)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcnRCoAgDEDRX9lLUGSy9dw@RmbBJDTEvn9Jvt3Dvd9gJoxwlQrKu/Pex/IrMTndCDob65QOgpAjJOivwdlTWNZRT9XcZlnMjBDxAw)

Answer (score 1):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 18 bytes

```
[:+/1}.&.q:@+}.@i.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/r/P83WKtpKW9@wVk9Nr9DKQbtWzyFT739qcka@QpqCoYGBwX8A)

Answer (score 1):

## [Stacked](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/stacked), 31 bytes

```
[2\|>[divisors:pop\MAX]map sum]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Ky5JTM5OTfn/P9oopsYuOiWzLLM4v6jYqiC/IMbXMSI2N7FAobg0N/a/g1Ual4aRgomCmYKFgqGpgrG5gqGBgaZCtIKVQpqCjoK6gq4dkMjKz8xTyC8tUYhVAGr9DwA) (All testcases except for 1000, which exceeds the 60 second online time limit.)

### Explanation

```
[2\|>[divisors:pop\MAX]map sum]
 2\|>                               range from 2 to the input inclusive
     [                ]map          map this function over the range
      divisors                      get the divisors of the number (including the number)
              :pop\                 pop a number off the array and swap it with the array
                   MAX              gets the maximum value from the array
                           sum      sum's all the max's
```

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 53 bytes

```c
x;s;f(n){for(s=0;n>1;--n){for(x=n;n%--x;);s+=x;}n=s;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PU9Na8MwDL33V4hAwCYRc9dmK2jefaf@gKaHYpriw9RRuxCW@rdncpLugaQn61kfDi/OjWNPgTrFeuiuNxWsIf5cE@Ly0FsmLhF70hQq21NiGyiNniN8nzwrPaxAkPPoDkewMMAr1LAVexPbia0bcZv3zIyZvYFE08efewyq@GKJAA@A/T0KbRlnVPhEyzDjUWj6nxn871lm5nDtVHQaXp6JlBdhPiSLvSgNSfiYNMKqatl/WuUmok4VUGLjZZcSd77los6H@WMNub8QvXRNqzT@AQ)

Comfortably an quickly passes all test cases.

Comment: [51 bytes](https://tio.run/##PU9Nb8IwDL3zK6xKlRK11gKjDMkLd077ASuHKaIoB8xEglRR@tuL0xaeZPs5fvGHw5Nzw9BSoEax7prLVQVriHdLQuQyFLbV6bG1TJwjtqSJbaB@8Bzh/OdZ6W4BgpRH93sACx2soIS12EZsK7asxH1@JWbM5A30NH78v8Wgsj1LBHgA/Nyi0JpxQoEv1AwTHpmm98zg70eZmcKlUdFp@HglUp6F6YQk9qI0JOF71Agrinn/cZWriBqVQY6Vl11y3PqaszId5g8lpP5C9Ny1X/TDEw "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 6](https://perl6.org), 36 bytes

```perl6
{sum map {max grep $_%%*,^$_},2..$_}
```

[Test it](https://tio.run/##TY7NboJAFIX39ynOAg1UHHFUlBCbbt132dRQmBoSBibMYDTUJ@vOF6ODYNK7uefkfPdHiboIu0YLnEOWxiSvmKZVJrDvWt1IyEShlckFp1ooOMfJ5MX/dI43nzNmW2f5NyO0wR5FXgrtevdfllbyy118ZLNF7w6liam/8G65mFSRlJg9hmL6rupxfv5qt8OFk5eqMT4ccVEiNSKD1xKQa/RvuUPs/ct9sFOuDd06cPT1gyVhPco1IRzljrB7AivCcjMSll5tB815ZIMgGKAwCh4uGNyGb6M/)

### Expanded:

```perl6
{
  sum
    map
    {
      max
        grep
        $_ %% *, # is the input to this block divisible by
        ^$_      # Range of possible divisors
    },
    2 .. $_
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Alice](https://github.com/m-ender/alice), 17 bytes

```
/o
\i@/&w!qB;?+]k
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8zJTE79/18/nysm00FfrVyx0MnaXjs2@/9/QwMDAwA)

### Explanation

This is a standard format for a program which takes input as an integer, outputs an integer, and does everything else in cardinal mode.

The program tries to add up the highest proper divisor of every number from 0 to n.  In the case of 0 and 1, the number added comes from the implicit zeros on the stack, so we don't have to bother skipping these cases.

```
i    Take input string (in ordinal mode)
&w   Implicitly convert into an integer, and push a return address n times.
     This starts the main loop, which will run a total of n+1 times.
!    Store the accumulator on the current tape cell.
q    Get the tape position. (initially zero)
B    Compute all divisors.
;    Remove the top of the stack (the number itself).
?    Copy accumulator back from tape.
+    Add to greatest proper divisor.
]    Move tape right.
k    Return to pushed return address.  The (n+1)st time through this loop, 
     there is nowhere to return to, and the program continues.
o    Output the integer (as a string in ordinal mode).
@    Terminate.
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Neim](https://github.com/okx-code/Neim), 7 bytes

```
Γ)
```

Explanation:

```
Example input: 6
        Inclusive range [1 .. input]
         stack: [1 2 3 4 5 6]
 Γ       For each...
          Get factors
           stack: [[1] [1 2] [1 3] [1 2 4] [1 5] [1 2 3 6]]
          Remove last element
           stack: [[] [1] [1] [1 2] [1] [1 2 3]]
          Get greatest element
           stack: [0 1 1 2 1 3]
      )  End for each
        Sum.
         stack: [8]
Implicit output: 8
```

[Try it!](http://178.62.56.56:80/neim?code=%F0%9D%90%88%CE%93%F0%9D%90%85%F0%9D%95%99%F0%9D%90%A0)%F0%9D%90%AC&input=1000&n=true)

Answer (score 1):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 25 bytes

Lack of builtins is sad.

```apl
+/((⌈/∘⍸0=g|⊢)¨1+g←⍳1-⍨⊢)
```

Alternative dfn version: `{+/{⌈/⍸0=⍵|⍨⍳1-⍨⍵}¨1+⍳1-⍨⍵}`

Explanation:

```apl
+/((⌈/∘⍸0=g|⊢)¨1+g←⍳1-⍨⊢)
                 g←⍳1-⍨⊢   ⍝ numbers from 1 to ⍵-1 - define as `g`
               1+          ⍝ increment: numbers from 2 to ⍵.
              ¨            ⍝ for each of these...
        0=g|⊢              ⍝ mark evenly divisible indexes with 1
    ⌈/∘⍸                   ⍝ pick largest of proper divisors
+/                         ⍝ sum all
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///P@1R2wRtfQ2NRz0d@o86Zjzq3WFgm17zqGuR5qEVhtrpQNlHvZsNdR/1rgCJAdUrmHGlKRibAwlDAwMDAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), <s>21</s> 20 bytes

```
+/{|/&~1!x%!x}'2_!1+
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.codeberg.page/k#eJw1j0uOgzAQRPd9io40XyHiD+YTfIJZzQGiaIIIBJQEM9iMiEJy9jGY1KZeddemytQjt5G8PdhqeF0N93f+s2IegElvL9vro0tLRBzkXp3kx77M6rMc5FV2n7u77Wy5ZDtrQorJIplMxkIp5nMQS84384lSyaINXXgKIY/tCwhUxrQ6JSRXh+KozuVamyw/FUNeZc2xWOfqQn77QptaNZownjARk7ZTbdH5h/qv1qrzL5mu/L4F+Gra3iCOiN+9sQi+k+c/Beg0AnIHyADFggIwWjABTJ6FAJCFS8O2g9ixHWcflLqSnTcn6tK07x+PkVkx)

- `2_!1+` generate integers in range 2..x
- `{|/&~1!x%!x}'` get largest divisor for each value in generated range
- `+/` take the sum

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-MList::Util=max -p`, 42 bytes

```perl
//,$\+=max grep$'%$_==0,1..$_-1for 2..$_}{
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/19fX0clRts2N7FCIb0otUBFXVUl3tbWQMdQT08lXtcwLb9IwQjErK3@/9/QwOBffkFJZn5e8X9dX5/M4hIrq9CSzBzb4tJcHaAJ/3ULAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `s`, 27 [bits<sup>v2</sup>](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyncode/blob/main/README.md), 3.375 bytes

```
ƛKṪt
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2#WyJzPSIsIiIsIsabS+G5qnQiLCIiLCIxMDAiXQ==)

### Explained

```
ƛKṪt­⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁪‏⁠⁪⁪‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌­
ƛ     # ‎⁡To each number 1..n
 KṪ   # ‎⁢Push the divisors of each number with that number removed
   t  # ‎⁣And get the last divisor remaining. Returns 0 on an empty list
```

Created with the help of [Luminespire](https://vyxal.github.io/Luminespire).

Answer (score 0):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 22 bytes

```
ＩＬ⪫Ｅ…·²Ｎ×⌈Ｅ…¹ι⎇﹪ιλ⁰λ1ω
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYvLDsIgFER/hXR1STABty5d1VhjjD@ASNqbwKXhUfXrEXQ1mZlzzKKjCdrVeo1IGY46ZThbmvMCp4AEk15hJONKws3eNM0W9oKNtJZ8Kf5hI3Au2B29TY19oy/@5/xRJRj220bS8QNTeBYXAAVzbZU9uj2oocerFX6oVUlZd5v7Ag) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
      ²                 Literal 2
       Ｎ                Input number
    …·                  Inclusive range
   Ｅ                    Map with variable `i`
            ¹           Literal 1
             ι          Variable `i`
           …            Exclusive range
          Ｅ             Map with variable `l`
                ι       Variable `i`
                 λ      Variable `l`
               ﹪        Modulo
              ⎇         Ternary
                  ⁰     If nonzero then zero
                   λ    If zero then variable `l`
         ⌈              Take the maximum
                    1   Arbitrary character
        ×               Repeat it
  ⪫                  ω  Join the strings together
 Ｌ                      Take the length
Ｉ                       Cast to string
                        Implicitly print
```

The `Sum` function has been added since the question was asked, reducing the code to 18 bytes:

```
ＩΣＥ…·²Ｎ⌈Ｅ…¹ι⎇﹪ιλ⁰λ
```

Answer (score 0):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 53 bytes

```r
function(n){for(i in 2:n)F=F+(y=(i-1):1)[!i%%y][1]
F}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfpmCj@z@tNC@5JDM/TyNPszotv0gjUyEzT8HIKk/TzdZNW6PSViNT11DTylAzWjFTVbUyNtowlsut9n@ahpnmfwA)

For each integer `i` in `2...n`, computes the divisors of `i` in decreasing order with `(y=(i-1):1)[!i%%y]` and then selects the first, as that will be the largest, adding it to `F`, which is by default initialized to `FALSE` or `0`.